# Storm is having trouble connecting to nimbus

Tags: java, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to set up a storm cluster but am having trouble running topologies on the cluster.  I can run them locally on each machine but not together.  I am using the following command from the storm starter kit to try and make it work:

```
$ storm jar storm-starter-*.jar storm.starter.RollingTopWords production-topology remote
```

I am getting two different but similar errors when I run the topology on one of the supervisor machines vs the nimbus machine.  I have an instance of zookeeper that my supervisor nodes should be able to connect to but clearly that is not happening.  Honestly, I don't even really understand how zookeeper manages the cluster.

Error thrown in supervisor:

```
scix3@M5:~/apache/storm/examples/storm-starter/target$  storm jar storm-starter-0.9.4.jar storm.starter.RollingTopWords production-topology remote

Running: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -client - Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/home/scix3/apache/storm -Dstorm.log.dir=/home/scix3/apache/storm/logs -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/kryo- 2.21.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/core.incubator-0.1.0.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/ring-servlet-  0.3.11.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/clj-stacktrace-0.2.2.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/jline-2.11.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/disruptor-2.10.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/clojure- 1.5.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/commons-exec-1.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/logback-core-1.0.13.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/carbonite-1.4.0.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/compojure- 1.1.3.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/minlog-1.2.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/tools.macro- 0.1.0.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/tools.cli-0.2.4.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/math.numeric-tower-0.0.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/tools.logging-0.2.3.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/asm-4.0.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/hiccup-0.3.6.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/clj-time-0.4.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/jgrapht-core-0.9.0.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/clout-1.0.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/chill-java-0.3.5.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/commons-io- 2.4.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/joda-time-2.0.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/storm-core-0.9.4.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/ring-core-1.1.5.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/ring-jetty-adapter-0.3.11.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/ring-devel-0.3.11.jar:storm-starter-0.9.4.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/conf:/home/scix3/apache/storm/bin - Dstorm.jar=storm-starter-0.9.4.jar storm.starter.RollingTopWords production-  topology remote
    200  [main] INFO  storm.starter.RollingTopWords - Topology name:  production- topology
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     com/google/common/collect/Lists
at storm.starter.tools.Rankings.<init>(Rankings.java:33) 
at storm.starter.bolt.AbstractRankerBolt.<init>   (AbstractRankerBolt.java:69)
at storm.starter.bolt.AbstractRankerBolt.<init> (AbstractRankerBolt.java:56)
at storm.starter.bolt.IntermediateRankingsBolt.<init>  (IntermediateRankingsBolt.java:41)
at storm.starter.RollingTopWords.wireTopology(RollingTopWords.java:68)
at storm.starter.RollingTopWords.<init>(RollingTopWords.java:52)
at storm.starter.RollingTopWords.main(RollingTopWords.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Lists
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 7 more
scix3@M5:~/apache/storm/examples/storm-starter/target$
```

Error thrown from nimbus:

```
scix3@M6:~/apache/storm/examples/storm-starter/targetstorm jar storm-starter-0.9.4.jar storm.starter.RollingTopWords production-topology remote
Running: java -client -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/home/scix3/apache/storm -Dstorm.log.dir=/home/scix3/apache/storm/logs - Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp  /home/scix3/apache/storm/storm-starter-0.9.4-jar-with- dependencies.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/storm-starter-0.9.4.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/clj-stacktrace- 0.2.2.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/clojure-1.5.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/minlog- 1.2.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/tools.logging-0.2.3.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/asm-4.0.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/ring-servlet-0.3.11.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/carbonite-1.4.0.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/tools.macro-0.1.0.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/jgrapht-core-0.9.0.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/kryo-2.21.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/logback-core-1.0.13.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/ring-devel-0.3.11.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/ring-jetty-adapter-0.3.11.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/tools.cli-0.2.4.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/math.numeric-tower-0.0.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/chill-java-0.3.5.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/clout-1.0.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/disruptor-2.10.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/joda-time-2.0.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/compojure-1.1.3.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/hiccup-0.3.6.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/commons-exec-1.1.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/core.incubator-0.1.0.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/storm-core-0.9.4.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/ring-core-1.1.5.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/jline-2.11.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/home/scix3/apache/storm/lib/clj-time-0.4.1.jar:storm-starter-0.9.4.jar:/home/scix3/.storm:/home/scix3/apache/storm/bin -Dstorm.jar=storm-starter-0.9.4.jar storm.starter.RollingTopWords production-topology remote
202  [main] INFO  storm.starter.RollingTopWords - Topology name: production-topology
237  [main] INFO  storm.starter.RollingTopWords - Running in remote (cluster) mode
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:  org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException:    Connection refused
at backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:38)
at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:116)
at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:70)
at storm.starter.util.StormRunner.runTopologyRemotely(StormRunner.java:45)
at storm.starter.RollingTopWords.runRemotely(RollingTopWords.java:78)
at storm.starter.RollingTopWords.main(RollingTopWords.java:129)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:183)
at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
at backtype.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin.connect(SimpleTransportPlugin.java:83)
at backtype.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.<init>(ThriftClient.java:63)
at backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient.<init>(NimbusClient.java:47)
at backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient.<init>(NimbusClient.java:43)
at  backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:36)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at     java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at     java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:178)
... 11 more
scix3@M6:~/apache/storm/examples/storm-starter/target$
```

Although I've come this far setting up storm and zookeeper I don't really understand how they work and why I have issues.  Any tips, regarding this issue or not, are more than welcome!

Comment: What are the contents of your storm.yaml file on your local machine, your nimbus node and supervisor node(s)? And what are the contents of your zoo.cfg file on your zookeeper node?

Comment: did you build the project ? its complaining about a missing jar which should be available under `com.google.guava` package